# jQuery text() with <select>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop downlist as follows:

```
<select id="example" name="example" runat="server">
```

which gets populated in the code behind like this:

```
example.DataSource = new CampControl().GetCountries();
example.DataTextField = "CountryDesc";
example.DataValueField = "ID";
example.DataBind();
example.Attributes.Add("multiple", "multiple");
```

and on the click of the items in the list I have a jQuery function:

```
$inputs = this.inputs,
$checked = $inputs.filter(':checked'),
$checked.each(function (index) {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
```

But `$(this).text()` is always coming back as an empty string,

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the value using this:

```
$inputs = this.inputs,
            $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked'),
$checked.each(function () {
               alert(($(this)[$(this).index()].title));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `:selected` attribute, not `:checked`

Comment: I have changes the selector to 
$checked = $inputs.filter(':selected'),

now im not getting any selected/checked items

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$inputs = this.inputs,
        $checked = $inputs.filter.is(':checked'),
 $checked.each(function (index) {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$inputs = this.inputs;
    $checked = $inputs.val();
    $checked.each(function (index) {
    alert($(this).text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In drop downlist we need to populate n'of option to select ,after selecting the option. we can get selected text using below query...

var exampleValue = $("#example option:selected").text();